# No Error in Typescript if spreading unknon property into variable

Tags: typescript, spread

I have a playground for this question [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=2&pln=21&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEYoG8BQUNQIYC4oDsBXAWwCMIAnAbnU1LyLMpoF9VVRJZ4AmKAXhS0MwBHjiQEwqAGc8M4BQCW%20AOat2AGwjAoo8fCSDkuBABp6PNtt3AAHgJR2cVmqht6eAfTHdIfY2lRM2k5KAAiLBkAEwAzcJDMKAA6VPtUNncdTy8eA39HNCTg0LxImPjEzGcoAGYMoA).

In the following code, typescript does error on the assignment to t2_2 ("not assignable") but not on t2_1, where I have the "x" property in some other variable, which I spread into the assignment.

Why does it not complain about the assignment to t2_1?

```
type Type1 {
    a: number;
    b: number;
}

type Type2 = {
    t1: Type1
    s: string;
}

let t1: Type1 = {a:1,b:2}
let tx = {x:2};

let t2_1: Type2 = {
    t1,
    s: "asdf",
    ...tx
}

let t2_2: Type2 = {
    t1,
    s: "asdf",
    x: 3
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you spread in `tx`, you don't know what properties it really has.
So TypeScript doesn't really know if you have excess properties in some cases.

However, `x` very explicitly appears to be an excess property.
It is statically known to be there - TS can always tell.

See

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14853
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12717
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2103#issuecomment-265513297

Comment: Thanks - fascinating that you found those spots. Didn't find them in the TS issues.